# Сравнение типов данных

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, я рассмотрел разные типы данных и сравнил их диапазон и расходуемую память, и возникли противоречия.
Именно:

- `short` и `int` имеют одинаковый диапазон, но разный "вес" -2 и 4 байта соответственно.
- `long` и `int` имеют одинаковый "вес" - 4 и 4 байта соответственно, но разный диапазон.

P.S замерял с помощью `sizeof()`, данные о диапазоне с Википедии.

Так почему такие различия, если я померил все правильно то тип `int` должен быть вообще не используемым, так как ему есть более "легкий" аналог - `short` и более вместительный аналог (по используемой памяти) - `long`.

Прошу помочь разобраться. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Целочисленные типы разного размера не могут иметь одинаковый диапазон. Вы что-то неправильно померили.

Comment: typeof(<переменная>) возвращает тип данных переменной. Используется для организации шаблонов функций и классов.

Comment: В [tag:c++] нет `typeof`.

Comment: Вот ссылка на статью в википедии о типах данных в с++: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_C и там, по-моему четко написано что размеры данных не регулируются стандартом а зависят от платформы. И на примере того же int и short пишут, что по крайней мере int равен short, но на практике равен 4 байт с диапазоном больше 4млрд (unsigned). И если уж замеряете размер, то не поленитесь замерять и диапазон - увидете, что диапазон всецело зависит от размера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данные о диапазонах лучше получать не из википедии, а из std::numeric_limits

```
#include <limits>
cout<<std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // вывод макс. значения int
```

Сделайте это на Вашей машине и сравните результаты.

Comment: только не <numeric_limits>, а просто <limits>

Comment: Сделал, как вы сказали, c short и int определился, а int и Long оказались идентичными:)

Comment: Кстати всегда интересовало, можно ли в C++ определять типы данных самостоятельно, то есть их диапазон(в целях экономия памяти).

Comment: C++11 определяет заголовочный файл <cstdint> (если такого нет, можно попробовать <stdint.h> ) в котором определяются типы int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t и соотв. беззнаковые uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t. Используя их можно быть уверенным в точном размере данных.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на подробное описание.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Правильно определились ? long и int на 32-bit х86 CPU совпадают. На 64-bit int останется 4, а long станет 8. Также 8-байтными станут все указатели, time_t, size_t и еще много.

А вот long long и там и там будет 8 байт.

Для других платформ цифры могут различаться.

Для экономии памяти с помощью диапазона значений посмотрите на fields. Можно указывать размер в битах. [Например](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax)

Comment: >На 64-bit int останется 4, а long станет 8.

 Не везде. Есть 3 модели данных, и только в одной из них long занимает 8. Такая модель используется, по-моему, только в Линуксе. В Windows всегда sizeof(long)==4.

Answer (score 4):

Размеры типов и диапазоны не оговариваются в стандарте и могут зависеть от платформы. Гарантируется только то, что `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`.

Про типы можно почитать [здесь](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) в разделе "Fundamental data types".

Comment: То есть в моем случае использовать short вместо int?

Comment: Обычно `short` — это целое число от -32768 до 32767.

Answer (score 2):

Это некоторый минус С и С++ - то, что на разных платформам одни и те же типы переменных имеют разные размеры и, соответственно, разные диапазоны данных. Стандартом определены только минимумы. При написании переносимого кода это создает некоторые затруднения, нужно как-то изощряться.

Comment: не нужно изощряться, нужно использовать <cstdint>

Comment: иногда это единственный выход создать гарантированно переносимый код. Но я это отношу к ряду извращений )) В норме должны быть переносимы стандартные типы.

Comment: Так это и есть стандартный заголовочный файл, определяющий стандартные типы.

Comment: Для каждой системы будут свои переопределения.

Замедляться программы не должны, все в любом случае приводится к word, dword и т.д. еще на стадии компиляции.

Comment: @mikillske раздел 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>. А иначе можно понять как требование иметь один процессор на все случаи жизни

Comment: >Это некоторый минус С и С++

 Да C++ вообще один сплошной минус. Я в нём разочаровался, но, к сожалению, альтернативы с такой производительностью ему нет. Я даже подумываю попробовать свой язык создать.

Comment: @GLmonster пытается спровоцировать очередной холивар? "альтернативы с такой производительностью ему нет"

Comment: Нет. Я имел в виду *подходящей мне* альтернативы...

Answer (score 0):

char - практически всегда 1 байт. signed char имеет диапазон [-128; 127], unsigned char - [0; 255]. Просто char по умолчанию зависит от компилятора и его настроек. Может быть как signed, так и unsigned. Остальные типы всегда по умолчанию signed.

short имеет размер 2. Диапазон [-32768; 32767], unsigned short - [0; 65535].

int на 16-разрядных процессорах аналогичен short, на всех остальных имеет размер 4 байта. Диапазон [-2147483648; 2147483647], unsigned - [0; 4294967295].

long почти всегда аналогичен int, но на linux x64 имеет размер 8 байт.

long long имеет размер 8 байт, но что будет, когда выйдут 128-разрядные процессоры не знаю. Диапазоны писать не буду, но они огромные.

Answer (score 0):

Типы `short`, `int`, `long` и `long long` не имеют стандартного размера. Как правило, их размер определяется исходя из процессорной архитектуры. Например, на `x86` `long` - 4 байта, на `x86_64` - 8 байт.

Есть ещё одна важная особенность в определении этих типов. Языки C и C++ создавались, чтобы работать на максимально возможном числе платформ. Некоторые платформы не поддерживают работу с памятью без выравнивания по размеру [машинного слова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE). Тип `long` является стандартным типом машинного слова в C и C++. На таких платформах адрес памяти всегда должен быть кратен `sizeof(long)`, и чаще всего, именно столько байт минимально мы можем прочитать из памяти за раз.

Хотя `x86` и последователи поддерживают не выровненный доступ к памяти, выровненный доступ всё равно, как правило, быстрее, поэтому подобная нотация типа `long` до сих пор важна.

Чтобы избавить людей от противоречий, были введены типы с фиксированным размером, например, `int32_t`, `uint8_t`, `int64_t`. В большинстве случаев при написании переносимых программ приоритет использования типов должен быть такой:

- Специальные типы (`size_t`, `off_t`). Применяем там, где они семантически выражают суть переменных.
- Типы с фиксированным размером. Так мы избегаем разных проблем при компиляции на 32 и 64 бита, особенно в работе с файлами и сетью.
- Классические типы (`int`, `short`, `long`), применяем для платформо-зависимых оптимизаций, и помним, что размер может измениться на другой платформе.